# Assigning Variable String Value to a table name

Tags: string, matlab, variables

I am creating a table in a function, so the function outputs a table to the assigned variable name as shown below

```
[name] = tablefunc(input1, input2)
```

The thing is I want to be able to have the name be an input that was assigned earlier for example

```
name = 'dogs'
[something] = tablefunc(input1,input2)
```

I want to be able to put some code where it says something so that the outputted table for tablefunc is assigned the variable name `dogs`

It might be confusing why I am doing this but it is because I am extracting tables from a txt file in a for loop so I am getting lots of tables generated and I want to be able to give the tables their appropriate names as opposed to just table1, table2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good idea. As an alternative, you should create a structure:

```
function t = tablefunc(input1,input2)
    t = table(input1,input2);
end

name = 'dogs';
s = struct();
s.(name) = tablefunc(rand(2),rand(2));
```

You can have one field per `txt` file.

Comment: That is very helpful. Can I add a new table to the structure each time I run through the for loop that it is embedded in though?

Comment: You are welcome. Of course, e.g. `s.('cats') = table()`

Comment: Never mind I changed the for loop to a while loop and it worked